# How to reference the desired constant when two classes have the same name in PHP?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am maintaining an old **Zend 1.12** application. This application has two classes named Document (`application/models/Document.php`), one of which holds a set of constants I need to reference.

Normally this works just fine. However, in one helper (`library/App/Helper/Action/Docusign.php`) a different Document class (`library/Docusign/APIService.php`) is being referenced for some reason I can't suss out, and of course it does not have the needed constants.

How can I specify which class it should be using in referencing the constant?

```
$documentType = Document::DOCUMENT_TYPE_OTHER;
```

> Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: Document::$DOCUMENT_TYPES in ...

I've tried messing around with various namespaces as well but no luck. Zend seems to be doing something behind the scenes to screw that up :P

Any advice out there for me?

Comment: Are these classes in namespaces?

Comment: They are not.  As I said, tho, I've messed about trying with namespaces to try and segregate them to no avail.  It claims it can't find the model's namespace when I define one, for instance, despite my having tried quite a few variations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no namespace based solution without tearing everything up and re-doing it to use namespaces properly throughout the app.

Instead, I refactored by changing one of the class names to DocumentModel from Document in order to force differentiation explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say, you aren't using any other namespaces, stick this at the very top of `library/Docusign/APIService.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Docusign;

...
```

Then, when referring to that different class, use this code:

```
$doc = new \Docusign\Document();
$documentType = Document::DOCUMENT_TYPE_OTHER;
```

---

Note that any object code *within* `library/Docusign/APIService.php` will need to be namespaced as well. So if you have a line like this:

```
$date = new DateTime();
```

You'd need to change it to:

```
$date = new \DateTime();
```

Comment: library/Docusign/APIService.php is actually already being used by default, perhaps that wasn't clear in my question - it's application/models/Document.php that I need to be made available.  I've actually already tried exactly that strategy to no avail - the Zend auto loader errors out saying it can't find the class, even tho it's located in one of the include paths (application/models).  As per some other resources I tried encoding the namespace as the relative path from the application root as well, but to the same effect.